# Create Excel file in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel

The requirement is to create an excel file in nodejs from json. The json will have around 50000 objects. I have got libraries which are asynchronous, but I want a library which does not do in memory - I mean, I should be able to stream the contents to a file.
If anybody can point me to such a library, it would be very helpful.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=excel

Answer (score 2):

This library works great with large amounts of data  [exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs).

I wrote an example, you can test here. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/gbahamondezc/excel-stream)